# Linux:load error:No such file or directory

Tags: linux

I am deploying a web server, and after I finish compiling.There are the executing documents;

`01client.c  client  epoll_server.c server`

Then I try to run server

```
./server
```

There is an error which I cant fix it. I have search ways for solving but still can't fix it.

```
load error: No such file or directory
```

Maybe some one can help me,please!

Thanks a lot!!!!

Answer (score 2):

System utilities print the program generating the error at the beginning of the line followed by other useful information such as the name of the missing file, so this is probably an error from a user program.  I can duplicate the error as follows:

```
errno = 2;
perror("load error");
```

which prints:

```
load error: No such file or directory
```

Look for the perror line in the server code.  If it isn't clear what file it can't find, print the string from the failed command it is reporting.

Comment: I am sorry that where i can find the failed command? Or can you answer the question more clearly? thank you!!

Comment: To search for a string in a group of files use grep